# HttpResponseValidator returns error in validateResponse

Tags: kotlin-multiplatform, ktor, ktor-client

I have an error response with response code 200, like this :

```
{"success":false,"message":"Users is not recognized","data":{"status":"Users is not recognized"}}
```

So according to the documentation I use this: https://ktor.io/docs/response-validation.html#2xx

now the problem is if my response doesn't fail he still thinks it's an error, like below:

```
failed with exception: io.ktor.serialization.JsonConvertException: Illegal input
```

Can't this be made for response code 200 validation?

Answer (score 1):

Looks like you have error because success response have different fields. You can pass `ignoreUnknownKeys` option in your json format instance and make `Error` data class fields optional

```kotlin
val httpClient = HttpClient {
    install(ContentNegotiation) {
        json(Json { ignoreUnknownKeys = true })
    }
    HttpResponseValidator {
        validateResponse { response ->
            val error: Error = response.body()
            if (error.success == false) {
                throw RuntimeException("Response is not success")
            }
        }
    }
}

@Serializable
data class Error(var success: Boolean?)
```

Also be aware there is an [open issue](https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/KTOR-4225/HttpResponseValidator-consumes-HTTP-response-body) with `HttpResponseValidator`. Current implementation consumes response content and you can't read it once again.

So unless this issue resolves, you will receive error every time you read content

```kotlin
httpClient.get("URL").body<SomeResponse>() // throws exception
```

Comment: I've added it, either ignoreUnknownKey = error or added Error class, but still get the same error, success if the validateResponse is removed, if it's still there it will generate that error